# Need advice about communication via serial port in C++/CLI

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++-cli, serial-port

I am working on project where I have to *communicate via serial port*. I will be receiving quite "large" amount of data **from UART via RS232 (approximately 6KB/10ms)** and I have to **collect it and decode it**. Decoded data will be **stored to files** and some of them will be **shown in GUI**.

I will be using **C++/CLI** (in **Visual Studio 2010** using **.NET v4.0)** because of managed data work and large amount of libraries.

And my **main question is:** What would you **recommend me**:

**A) To not use threads and look for data each 5ms via timer...**

**B) To not use threads and look for data based on event of incoming data...**

**C) Use threads...**

What would you recommend me? I have not much experience to tell what will be the best solution.

Thank you for your future responses...

Comment: That depends. Is the SOLE purpose of the program to wait for that data, until it gets killed by CTRL-C? If so, then 'select' on the serial port may be the most viable solution. If you'd like to interact with the program in any way, I am afraid that Threads will be your best bet.

Comment: there's almost as much bold as normal text, kinda defeats the purpose..

Comment: I was trying to high-lite important information. But the solution are threads. Stijn is totally right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need a gui, you will need a seperate thread to get the data. There's no way to reliably get data each x mSec and process it in a ui thread.

Apart from that you seem somehwat confused about what a thread does: A and B can be combined with C. I'd recommend using a seperate thread polling the port for data or use an event to check when new data arrives. Timer might be inaccurate, and after all it's the port dictating at what rate the data comes in so it's better to listen to that instead of using a seperate timebase. Store the processed data on a queue (aka *producer*) and have yet another thread (aka *consumer*) get large chunks from the queue to flush them to files (you do not want to write a file every 5mSec, instead write a large amount of data in one go every 100mSec or so).
The ui thread can then also preview from that queue and displays pieces of the data.

Comment: Thanks, I thought the same thing but I was thinking about not using threads.

Comment: Nah - use a thread, a producer-consumer queue and a 'Buffer' class that you can easily move/queue around by address, to save copying the data.  Load up a *Buffer from the COM port in the thread, queue it off an immediately create a new *Buffer in the same var for the next load of data.  Sounds like a 10K buffer member in the Buffer class would be fine.  Don't use unreseatable C++ references or any stack objects - use new() and pointers.

Comment: ..and after processing the *Buffers, don't forget to delete() them!  there are faster mechanisms using *Buffer pools, but I don't think you really need that sort of hammer for a miserable COM port.  If you need to display some of the data in your GUI, you will have to PostMessage() the *Buffer instances to the GUI - fairly trivial - just cast them to lParam, say, (or use BeginInvoke, or Dispatcher, or whatever GUI comms stuff you usually use).

Comment: Thanks guys for advice. I have already solve it. And it seems that it is working. Martin James: I am using managed C++ (C++/CLI) so it is bit easier ;) Thanks.